# Using Valgrind on a program not invoked from command line

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I want to use Valgrind to debug a memory issue in my C++ program (running on Linux-x64). My program outputs a .so library which is used by a much larger program. The invocation is not from command line, so I cannot use the following command to run the library with Valgrind -

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes myprog arg1 arg2
```

How can I use Valgrind to debug memory issues in my library?

Comment: I don't think you can test only the library. I think you should write some kind of tests and run them as _program", passed to `valgrind`. I don't have that much experience with `valgrind`, but I still think this is the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be two program involved:

1. The program creating the shared object. To run this with valgrind you can just wrap it in a shell script to invoke it with valgrind.
2. The program loading the shared object. You cannot run parts of a program with valgrind, i.e., just your shared object. You need to run the entire program with valgrind.

You should probably look at creating reasonably test cases running your code independent from the "much larger program" and analyze those.